# LocalStorage noUiSlider values || Important! : (

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-slider

I wanna storage 2 variables(?) values to local storage and load them if the website is refreshed.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
 start: [60, 600],
 connect: true,
 range: {
  'min': 50,
  'max': 700
 }
});

var sliderValue = slider.noUiSlider.get();
var min = parseInt(sliderValue[0]); //Need to storage this value
var max = parseInt(sliderValue[1]); //Need to storage this value
console.log(Math.floor((Math.random() * (max-min)) + min));
```

```css
#slider {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/8.2.1/nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/8.2.1/nouislider.min.js"></script>



<div id="slider">

</div>
```

!Important! My js knowledge is kinda little so if you wanna explain me anything, talk like you are talking to a baby. Indeed.

Comment: Just use localStorage.setItem and localStorage.getItem, localStorage.setItem to store in the localstorage and localStorage.getItem to retrieve from localstorage

Comment: I don't really know how to do it. :/ I'm kinda new to this : /

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/ozfpr1cn/1/

```js
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');

var start;
if(localStorage.getItem('noUISlider') == null){
 start = [60, 600];
}else{
 start = $.map(localStorage.getItem('noUISlider').split(","), function(value){
    return parseFloat(value, 10);
  });
}

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
 start: start,
 connect: true,
 range: {
  'min': 50,
  'max': 700
 }
});

var sliderValue = slider.noUiSlider.get();
slider.noUiSlider.on('change', function(){
 localStorage.setItem('noUISlider', slider.noUiSlider.get());
});
```

```css
#slider {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/8.2.1/nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/8.2.1/nouislider.min.js"></script>

<div id="slider">

</div>
```

Comment: You are literally a god. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use localStorage APIs to set and get items:

First if you want to store item in the localStorage, just use the set API:

```
localStorage.setItem('myValue', sliderValue[0]);
```

where myValue is the item name

Second if you want to get the localStorage, just use get API:

```
localStorage.getItem('myValue');
```

Comment: Item name, what do you mean by that? Can it be anything or the variable name?

Comment: Just a name you choose to identify the Item.

Comment: I've tried something like this https://codepen.io/Hatchling/pen/EXqeRN but it doesn't work. ;/

Comment: Good use, but if you want to store multi value in the same item it is recommended using object like: var items = [];

function store(item_id) {
    items.push(item_id);
    localStorage.setItem("item", JSON.stringify(items));
}

Comment: Alright, but even when I tried to save only 1 value to localStorage which was only the sliderValue[0] it didn't work too. ;/

Comment: you can test that by open your browser developer tool -> applications -> localStorage to see if there is a value or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149765/discussion-between-fady-saad-and-hatchling).

Comment: It is, but when I am getting it back with the localStorage.getItem();  it doesn't move the slider to the previous place. : /

Comment: I think this is not a localstorage issue it is a slider issue, I think you should parse it to int because it is a string value, by parseInt(localStorage.getItem('SliderValues')